マリネする vs. マリネにする "to marinate"
I was looking at example sentences for the word マリネ "marinate", and I found this as a common usage:

►マリネにする　marinate.

I understand many nouns related to cooking are used often as XをYにする "to make X into Y", but I usually understand this usage as related to the form of an ingredient, like:

乱切りにする　
chop up 《a carrot》 (into small pieces).
[to make into roughly chopped shapes (of vegetables, etc.)]

But from my perspective you don't really change the form (at least not as visually significantly as chopping) of an ingredient when you marinate it. However, this word can also just mean marinated food, so I think that is how it is used with にする.
However, you can also say マリネする apparently.
What is the difference between マリネする and マリネにする?

As you pointed out, マリネ refers to certain cuisine (marinated food) so the expression マリネにする focuses on the product and not on the process, while マリネする focuses on the cooking method of marinating. The confusing point is that method and product are both called マリネ.
Theoretically, when you say マリネにする, you can use any method as long as resulting in marinated food, but in reality, no one can make marinated food without marinating. And similarly, you can マリネする in order to make something but marinated food.
By the way, I found an interesting sentence from the internet

冷蔵庫で15分マリネする (https://onnela.asahi.co.jp/article/74598)

This マリネする cannot be replaced with マリネにする as it refers to the state that the meat is being marinated in fridge.
